# Unsupported Uri in ContentResolver when passing Uri returned by Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-contentresolver

I have an app where the user can add music files by selecting a file or adding all the files in a selected directory into a `ListView`. When adding a single file, everything is fine, but for directories I'm getting `Unsupported Uri`. Problem is not related to permissions:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.dibo.testapp, PID: 12226
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65579, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/2006 A Good Year flg=0xc3 }} to activity {com.example.dibo.testapp/com.example.dibo.testapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported Uri content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/raw%3A%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2F2006%20A%20Good%20Year
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4360)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4402)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:49)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported Uri content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/raw%3A%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2F2006%20A%20Good%20Year
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:167)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:418)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:802)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:752)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:710)
        at com.example.dibo.testapp.PlaylistFragment.addFolder(PlaylistFragment.java:380)
        at com.example.dibo.testapp.PlaylistFragment.onActivityResult(PlaylistFragment.java:346)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:160)
        at com.example.dibo.testapp.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:152)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7454)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4353)
```

**This is intent request:***

```
private void selectDirectory() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);

    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_FOLDER);
}
```

**Result handler:**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                             Intent resultData) {

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_FILE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (resultData != null) {
            addFile(resultData.getData());
        }
    }

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_FOLDER && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

        if (resultData != null) {
            addFolder(resultData.getData());
        }
    }
}

private void addFolder(Uri uri) {

    ContentResolver contentResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();

    if (contentResolver==null) {
        return;
    }

    Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(
            uri, // Uri
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );

    if (cursor != null &&  cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        int Title = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);

        do {

            String SongTitle = cursor.getString(Title);
            Log.d("addFolder", SongTitle);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.close();
    }

}
```

Exception is raised in `contentResolver.query`. Note that everything is in `Fragment` Class, not in `Activity`.

Comment: and have you tried with a folder without spaces in its name?

Comment: @Blundell Hey, thanks for the response! I don't think that's the problem, since even if he removes the spaces from the folder name, some special characters like `%2F` (`/` path separator) would still appear in the directory string.

Comment: @Enzo: There is no requirement for an arbitrary `Uri` to support `MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE`. If you want a display name for a document `Uri`, use `DocumentFile`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I got your point, but I don't think that's the problem either, since the error doesn't occur when he tries to get the `MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE` column, it occurs when he creates the `Cursor`, on `contentResolver.query`. It's weird, since Google has [a page with an example similar to the OP's one](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#examine-metadata), but anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: OP should still try these things to minimise the problem Space Enzo. Another strange thing is the `/:raw/` folder, strange prefix. I see they're trying on an emulator, is this an emulator only problem?

Answer (score 14):

You need first do magic thing:

```
Uri docUriTree = DocumentsContract.buildDocumentUriUsingTree(treeUri, DocumentsContract.getTreeDocumentId(treeUri));
```

Then you can read DocumentsContract.Document values from your Uri.

Comment: Hi, what is the use of this function? Why is the `Uri` returned in document tree picker not enough?

Comment: The relevant data is just stored under a different key in the database, in the manner of speaking. Under the hood, this just adds more segments to the path in the URI. The result tests positive as both tree URI and document URI.

Comment: no idea what this code does but it works... what the hell Google?

Comment: this is not the actual path, its create a new path !